# Expecting str found float error while adding zeros

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The code that i am using for adding zeros to date column is shown below. The Date is of object data type.

Eg of data is 7-05-2020.

```
df['Date'] = (
    df['Date']
    .str.split("-", expand=True)
    .stack()
    .str.zfill(2)
    .unstack()
    .agg("-".join, axis=1))
```

I am getting the error as  sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should add one function at a time, and check results, until you find the error (either unexpected output, or just python error). This is the best (and quick) way to debug

Comment: could you add exemplary content of `df['Date']`?

Comment: this is an over complex implementation of `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: @RobRaymond: I was about to suggest the same but with the datetime parser, a lot of stuff is happening in the background - it might be more efficient to edit the strings directly if you only want them in a certain format. Although I have slight doubts that this is the OP's primary concern.

Comment: @ Rob Raymond thanks, yeah..mine was probably too complicated.